# Bound symmetric tensor by its action on powers?

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

Let $A_{ijk}$ be a symmetric tensor (meaning that $A_{ijk}=A_{jik}=A_{kij}=\cdots$).
Is there a bound of the form

$$
|A_{ijk}| \leq C(d) \sup_{\|x\|_2=1} \left| \sum_{i,j,k=1}^d x_ix_jx_k A_{ijk}\right| ?
$$

In other words, is the seminorm

$$
|A|_{pow} := \sup_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \left| \sum_{ijk} x_ix_jx_k A_{ijk} \right|
$$

a norm when restricted to the subspace of symmetric tensors?

For the case of matrices this is a consequence of the polarization identity,
$$
x^{\top} A y = \frac{1}{2} \big((x+y)^{\top} A (x+y) + (x-y)^{\top} A (x-y)\big).
$$
Perhaps there is an analogous identity in the case of tensors?  I am not sure because I know many facts about matrices do not generalize to tensors.